# Is there "includePath" option in clangd?

Tags: c++, c, neovim, clangd

I used to work with VSCode [C/C++](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools) extension. there was a feature in this extension(in a json file), called "includePath", which I could set the paths for my headers, so without execution of CMake or make, I would have the suggestion of my headers and code completion from those.

now I have switched to neovim and clangd as the language server for code completion. I searched a lot to find the corresponding feature in clangd options but I could not find anything more than [this link](https://manpages.debian.org/experimental/clangd/clangd.1.en.html).

since the clangd is a powerful language server, I am in wonder if there is not such a feature in it. so I want to know is there actually such a feature in clangd? and if YES how can I use that?

Note: I use a language client, called ["coc-clangd"](https://github.com/clangd/coc-clangd). I don't know if it matters or not.

Comment: You need to provide `compiler_commands.json`, see: https://clangd.llvm.org/installation.html

Comment: I know that. but I use the catkin_make(ROS platform) which automatically generates CMake files and then I generate compile_commands.json base on it. so if I want to automate the process I can't use this file for doing that.

Answer (score 16):

Maybe this is useful: https://clangd.llvm.org/config

Create a file called '.clangd' in the top-level of the source directory.
Add those content.

```yaml
CompileFlags: # Tweak the parse settings, example directory given to show format
  Add:
    # - "-I=[folder]"         # old answer
    - "-I[folder]"            # e.g `-I/usr/include/SDL2`  suggested from @Palmkeep
```

But I think this is not recommend, all include directories should be add in `CMakeLists.txt` file.

Comment: Note: if you use clangd in Visual Studio Code you will have to add `--enable-config` to `Clangd: Arguments` in VS Code settings for it to use the .clangd file [source](https://blogs.igalia.com/aboya/2021/10/02/setting-up-visualstudio-code-to-work-with-webkitgtk-using-clangd/). Also I found that `"-I=path/to/dir"` did not work but `"--include-directory=path/to/dir"` did work.

Comment: @hideDragon I presume that all include directories that you add in `CMakeLists.txt` file are then also inside the `compile_commands.json`. But! I think that you should create `.clangd` file nevertheless! This is because in this configuration file you first **point** the `clangd` to the `compile_commands.json` using the command `CompileFlags:` and it's member `CompilationDatabase: ./build` *(if your `compile_commands.json` is inside the `build` sub folder of your project)* ([link](https://clangd.llvm.org/config#compilationdatabase)) and from there onwards it can function on it's own...

Answer (score 15):

Clangd uses `compile_commands.json` database file which contains flags (such as include directories) for each file in project. But this file is auto-generated, so all modifications to it will be overwritten eventually. You can ask CMake to add any custom compile flags with `-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` command line argument.

Example for system headers (`#include <file.h>`):

```
cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-isystem /path/to/includes" /path/to/source
```

For project headers (`#include "file.h"`):

```
cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-Ipath/to/includes /path/to/source
```

Additionally, you can set `CXXFLAGS` environment variable:

```
export CXXFLAGS="-isystem /path/to/includes"
cmake path/to/sources
```

After that new flags should appear in your `compile_commands.json` file.

Comment: FYI if you need to generate `compile_commands.json` you can use `bear -- make` to generate it.

Comment: This worked for me, I was having a similar issue but with standard libraries like `#include <iostream>`, I was struggling to know which paths to use for system headers, I ran this to know the include paths `gcc -H mySrcFile.cpp`, this is how I run CMake now `mkdir -pv $BUILD_DIR && cd $BUILD_DIR && cmake .. -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=1 -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-isystem /usr/include/c++/11/ -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/11/" && make run`

Answer (score 14):

You can add `includePath` to `clangd.fallbackFlags` into vscode's `settings.json` like this:

```
"clangd.fallbackFlags": [
    "-I${workspaceFolder}/include",
    "-I/my/include"
]
```

Answer (score 7):

To use code completion provided by Clangd, let Clangd retrieve include paths from `compiler_commands.json` with compiler calls used by CMake. Set the [CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS.html) option in `CMakeLists.txt`, it will output `compiler_commands.json` to the build directory when CMake is run:

```
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)
```

Copy the generated `compiler_commands.json` to the project source directory. Clangd will now source this file.

Comment: So does one have to add include paths to `cmake` first and then `cmake` will include these include paths in the `compiler_commands.json` when it auto generates it?

Comment: copying the `compiler_commands.json` to the workspace directory did not help. I'm testing this on oxen-io/oxen-core.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CPATH` environment variable. Syntax is the same as `PATH` variable.

```
export CPATH="your/include:more/include:/usr/include"
```