# nvim clangd problem with #define, #ifdef, and BEGIN_DECLS

Tags: c, neovim, clangd, libopencm3

[This](https://github.com/mehdi-norouzi/clangd-test) is a minimal stm32 project based on libopencm3 library.

The problem is clangd language server in neovim, does not detect definitions in some header files and throws errors. For example if you open the header file `libopencm3/stm32/dma.h` which is included in `main.c`, the line `#include <libopencm3/stm32/f4/dma.h>` should be active due to definition of `STM32F4` in makefile. Now if you open `libopencm3/stm32/f4/dma.h` here is the file contents:

```
#ifndef LIBOPENCM3_DMA_H
#define LIBOPENCM3_DMA_H

#include <libopencm3/stm32/common/dma_common_f24.h>

#endif
```

Two diagnostic messages are displayed in this file. In first line:

```
Too many errors emitted, stopping now
```

and in the `#include ...` line:

```
In included file: unknown type name BEGIN_DECLS
```

And int the `dma_common_f24.h` file, the lines between `#ifdef LIBOPENCM3_DMA_H` and `#else` are grayed out, and the warning message in the bottom line is active despite definition of the `LIBOPENCM3_DMA_H` in the `dma.h` file.

The project builds and runs with no errors or warnings. But the code completion and go-to-definition (in this case, for dma function) doesn't work due to the LSP issue.

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67207691/9439683) I tried adding include paths to the `.clangd` file in my project root directory, but that didn't solve the problem.

For building the project using **arm-none-eabi-gcc**:

```
git clone https://github.com/mehdi-norouzi/clangd-test.git
cd clangd-test
git submodule init && git submodule update
cd libopencm3 
make TARGET=stm32/f4
cd ..
make
```

`compile_commands.json` will be in the `build` directory. Also you may have to change the `--sysroot` path in `.clangd` file based on the directory of the toolchain.

**PS:** Vscode and intellisense have no LSP errors in this project and completion and go-to-definition are functioning correctly.

Comment: what is lsp error?

Comment: clangd https://clangd.llvm.org/ is a editor agnostic language server that hooks with neovim (which support language server protocol (LSP)) and performs static code analysis (showing errors and warnings in virtual text) and code completion in the editor.